# MPI_Allreduce doubles

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to find the global min and max values across all processors for a sort I am working on. I am trying to use `MPI_Reduceall`

```
int rank, nproc;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nproc);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

vector< vector<double> > buckets(nproc);
double local_min = *std::min_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());
double local_max = *std::max_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());

int min = 0;
int max = 0;

double global_min;
double global_max;

MPI_Allreduce(&local_min, &global_min, 1, MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Allreduce(&local_max, &global_max, 1, MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_MAXLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

cout << "local_min " << local_min << " local_max " << local_max << endl;
cout << "global_min " << global_min << " global_max " << global_max << endl;
```

My code is shown, and segfaults every time. This is in a simple function and is called with random doubles generated using:

```
int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    vector<double> values_to_sort;
    vector<double> sorted_values;
    for(int i=0; i< 1000; i++)
    {
      values_to_sort.push_back( ((double) rand()*(max-min)/(double)RAND_MAX-min) );
    }
```

If anyone knows why this seg faults, please let me know. I would really like to get the global max and min in a quick easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some reading and the MINLOC and MAXLOC operations requires that you use an array of some size > 1 to store the value and rank as a pair.

My updated code

```
 int rank, nproc;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    vector< vector<double> > buckets(nproc);
    double local_min[2];
    local_min[1] = rank;
    local_min[0] = *std::min_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());

    double local_max[2];
    local_max[1] = rank;
    local_max[0] = *std::max_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());

    double global_min[2];
    double global_max[2];

    MPI_Allreduce(&local_min, &global_min, 1, MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Allreduce(&local_max, &global_max, 1, MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_MAXLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout << "local_min " << local_min[0] << " local_max " << local_max[0] << endl;
    cout << "global_min " << global_min[0] << " global_max " << global_max[0] << endl;
```

Comment: You might be better off with a different pair type, eg int+double.

Comment: `MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION` is a Fortran MPI type, not a C++ one. You shouldn't use it in a C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use `MPI_MINLOC` and `MPI_MAXLOC` here? Because the way you stated your problem and the way you use the solution, `MPI_MIN` and `MPI_MAX` would do just fine:

```
double local_min = *std::min_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());
double local_max = *std::max_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());

double global_min;
double global_max;

MPI_Allreduce(&local_min, &global_min, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Allreduce(&local_max, &global_max, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

cout << "local_min " << local_min << " local_max " << local_max << endl;
cout << "global_min " << global_min << " global_max " << global_max << endl;
```

Now, if you really need the rank of the process owning the global min and global max, then you indeed need `MPI_MINLOC` and `MPI_MAXLOC`. However, you are supposed to use it like this:

```
struct double_int {
    double val;
    int rank;
} local_min, local_max, global_min, global_max;

local_min.val = *std::min_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());
local_max.val = *std::max_element(values_to_sort.begin(), values_to_sort.end());
local_min.rank = local_max.rank = rank;

MPI_Allreduce(&local_min, &global_min, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_INT, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Allreduce(&local_max, &global_max, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_INT, MPI_MAXLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

cout << "on process " << rank << " local_min " << local_min.val
     << " local_max " << local_max.val << endl;
cout << "global_min " << global_min.val << " owned by process " << global_min.rank << endl;
cout << "global_max " << global_max.val << " owned by process " << global_max.rank << endl;
```